# Can $5^n+1$ be sum of two squares?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

I want to determine whether or not $5^n+1$ , $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be written as sum of two squares.
Obviously, the real problem is when $n$ is odd. I am aware of the known results about numbers written as sum if squares, but I couldn't apply them here. We can see that when $n$ is odd, $5^n+1$ ia divisible by 6 and gives reminder 2 when divided by 4 which means that the two squares we would have to add must end in 1 and 9 or 5 and 5.

Comment: Don't you mean $n \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question

Comment: How would you write $5^1 + 1$ as the sum of two squares. $6= 0+6;1+5; 2+4;3+3$ none of which work.

Comment: $5^4+1=1^2+25^2$, is an obvious example....similarly for all even $n>2$.  But, say, $5^3+1$ can not be so written.

Comment: Note:  if $n$ is odd, then $5^n+1$ is divisible by $3$.  That doesn't rule it out, of course, but you would need  an even power of $3$ to divide it...and then there are the other primes congruent to $3\pmod 4$.  Seems difficult to find an odd example.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for n odd but I can't find a proof

Comment: I would expect it to be difficult.  A quick search through the first 20 or so odd exponents shows, as expected, that there is always a prime congruent to $3\pmod 4$ which divides $5^n+1$ to odd order.  The prime $3$ works most of the time, but not always.  Seems hard to prove in general...and maybe it's not even true.  I stopped looking somewhere around $5^{37}+1$...not that deep a search, really.

Answer (score 3):

Say $x^2 + y^2 = 5^n + 1$.

Looking mod 2, we get that $x^2 + y^2 = 0 \mod 2$, so $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, and looking mod 4, we get that $x^2 + y^2 = 2 \mod 4$, so $x$ and $y$ must both be odd.

Say $x = 2r + 1$ and $y = 2s+ 1$, so $$x^2 + y^2 = (2r + 1)^2 + (2s+1)^2 = 4(r^2 + r + s^2 + s) + 2 = 5^n + 1$$

or

$$4(r(r+1) + s(s+1)) = 5^n - 1$$

Now, the left side must be divisible by $8$, so $n$ must be even.

Comment: More briefly, for odd $n$, $5^n+1\equiv 6 \pmod 8$, but since squares can only be $0,1$ or $4 \pmod 8$, no two can add up to $6 \pmod 8$.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you're "aware of the known results about numbers written as sums of squares". Let's try to apply them here (just for fun, because the solution by @Michael Biro is perfectly elementary). We have the classical theorem : $x\in \mathbf N$ is a sum of two squares iff, for all primes $p\equiv 3$ mod $4$, the $p$-adic valuation $v_p(x)$ is even. It's not perhaps superfluous to recall the principle of the proof : every $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$ is a sum of two squares, so, by multiplicativity, it remains only to study the divisibility of $x$ by the primes $p\equiv 3$ mod $4$. Such a prime $p$ is inert (i.e. remains prime) in the PID $\mathbf Z[i]$, so if $x=a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi), p$ divides both the factors.

Now $3$ is inert and $5$ splits as $(2+i)(2-i)$ in $\mathbf Z[i]$. But $ 5^{2m+1} = (6-1)^{2m+1}=6^{2m+1}- 6^{2m}+...+6-1$ by the binomial formula, so $ 5^{2m+1}+1=6(6^{2m}-...+1)$, whose $3$-adic valuation is $1$. This shows that the exponent in your problem must be even.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial observation**

Let $n=2m+1$

$$5^n+1 \mod 3 = 3 \mod 3=0$$

So $3|5^n+1$. We can reduce the cases by observating that:
$$5^n+1\equiv 0 \mod 9 \Rightarrow n=6k+3$$
So if $n\neq6k+3$, it can't be expressed as sum of two squares because it contains $3^1$ in its factorization. In that case it may be useful:

$$5^{6k+3}+1=(5^{2k+1}+1)(5^{4k+2}-5^{2k+1}+1)$$

**Improvement**

Notice that :

$$5^{6k+3}+1\equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

So to be a sum of squares it must be:

$$5^{6k+3}+1\equiv 0 \pmod{49} \Rightarrow  k\equiv 3 \pmod 7 $$

So our new exponents are of this form $$n_2=6(7k+3)+3=42k+21=21(2k+1)$$
Now notice that:
$$ n_1=6k+3=3(2k+1) $$
$$ n_2=42k+21=3\times7(2k+1) $$

If we could prove that this process goes on infinitely than the thesis would be demonstrated. But i don't know how.

:/

Comment: I think you can finish now with an argument mod $43$, since $5^{21}\equiv-1$ mod $43$.